# How to set all the bits in a char array to zeros?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, bit

I am creating a char pointer to an array and wanted to initilaize it so that all elements in the array have 0 (in bits). So for example:

```
char* buffer = new char[bufferSize];
```

buffer[0] to buffer[bufferSize] will have '00000000' stored in each index. I am trying to store 8 bits of zeros in each cell.

How can i initialize it? I am also supposed to use fill().

So far,

```
fill(&buffer, &buffer[bufferSize], 0)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: *"`buffer[0]` to `buffer[bufferSize]`"* -- you mean `buffer[bufferSize-1]`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `fill`, but you must remember it accepts a pair of iterators. A pointer to the array elements is an iterator of the array already. There is no need to take the address of an iterator to pass it, so your first argument is incorrect. The more correct form would be

```
std::fill(buffer, buffer + bufferSize, 0);
```

or

```
std::fill_n(buffer, bufferSize, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can just zero initialize the array in the new expression itself

```
char* buffer = new char[bufferSize] {} ;
                                  // ^ - initializer, for char this will zero out the array.
```

Comment: suppose i need to reuse my buffer that's already filled with different chars. Now I have to reuse the same buffer and zero out the contents first. Do i need to delete the contents first before filling it again with 0s? I seem to be getting segfaults when testing it.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is with a string:

```
std::string buffer(bufferSize, '\0');
```

if you insist on using a `char*`, use `calloc`:

```
char* buffer = static_cast<char*>(std::calloc(bufferSize, 1));
```

If you already have the buffer, you can zero it out with `memset`:

```
std::memset(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

Comment: Careful with `calloc` in terms of you can't free it with `delete`, so you have to make sure to use `free`.